# Ubuntu 18.04 Intel wireless-AC 9260 connectivity issues / freezes on dell precision 5530

Tags: networking, 18.04, dell, iwlwifi

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 as dualboot next to Windows on my Dell Precision 5530. I have got issues with the wifi connection. I can connect to my wifi network as one would expect. But when as I start a download, it loads a couple of mb and then the download fails due to a network error. Also the touchpad does not work for a brief moment and the whole system freezes or is laggy for a short period. It feels like something crashes as soon as there is load on the wifi chip and it takes a while to recover.

I'm not very experienced with linux so I hope you can help me to resolve this issue. My current workaround is to use a USB Wifi dongle, which is pretty slow.

What I tried so far:

- Disable fastboot in windows.
- Install the intel driver from their [website](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html), but im not sure if extracting the files to `/lib/firmware` **is** installing.

Here is my output from running after reproducing the issue: 
`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info`

https://pastebin.com/9etY3npA

Here is some more info requested in the comments:

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        3,5G        3,1G        1,2G        8,7G         10G
Swap:          2,0G        627M        1,4G
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell Precision 5530

You have a very old BIOS, 1.6.0, dated 12/3/2018.

There's a newer BIOS available, 1.16.2, dated 5/13/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5530-laptop/drivers).

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

We see these interesting clues in your wireless_info:

> Queue 0 is inactive on fifo 2 and stuck for 2500 ms. SW [145, 146] HW
>   [162, 162] FH TRB=0x0a5a5a5a2

Which leads to this: https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490TtKSAU/dual-band-wirelessac-7260-iwlwifi-queue-2-stuck-for-10000-ms-microcode-sw-error-detected-restarting-0x2000000?language=en_US and then to this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194853

> Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 adapter hungs with 40MHz width
>   connection

We also see:

> Reason: 6=CLASS2_FRAME_FROM_NONAUTH_STA

Which leads to this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=220809

> Update: I solved the issue by deactivating the "WiFi Coexist" option
>   in my FritzBox router which apparently switches from 40MHz to 20MHz
>   every time it detects too many 40MHz routers nearby. This makes the
>   ath10k firmware crash (my old laptop and my phone handle those
>   switches nicely).

I recommend that you change the settings in the router to specify a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds.

If you do not have administrative priveleges for the router, then try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.